# Can You Trigger a Tag Based on Region in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to fire a tag from Google Tag Manager, using the location of a web visitor as the trigger? I'm asking specifically in regards to wanting to fire an EU cookie notification, but only have it appear to visitors from the EU.

Ideally, I would be able to set-up this up in GTM. If it is possible, can someone please explain how to do it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GTM itself cannot determine the location of the user. But of course you can use a custom HTML tag with a script to determine location, either via the geolocation API (which will require the users permission) or via a third party service that allows you to resolve IP addresses via a Javascript API (these service are usually commercial, plus it's expensive in terms of browser resources).

It would be much better for page performance to resolve the IP serverside to a location and push the location to the dataLayer. Then you could trigger or block your tags depending on location. To be legally on the safe side you should anonymize the IP before you use it for geolocation by setting the last tuple to 000 - that will be exact enough to determine if the user falls under EU jurisdiction while obscured enough to not constitute personally identifiable data.

Comment: Great info agreed, what would you recommend in terms of service when doing it on the server? Can a static table work - when looking for just a isUserInEu() // true or false?